# How can i have multiple slide up instances based on duplicate classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle, multiple-instances

Im using something similar on the frontend to the following code:

```
<div class="slide_toggle">
    <div class="slide_up">
      <p>Title 1</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slide_toggle">
    <div class="slide_up">
      <p>Title 2</p>          
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slide_toggle">
    <div class="slide_up">
      <p>Title 3</p>          
    </div>
</div>
```

So basically what i aim to achieve is have the "slide_up" divs slide up on hovering the "slide_toggle" using jQuery. So far im using the following jQuery which would work perfectly for one instance however i want each instance to work individually without having to process the jquery over again referring to different classes (i.e. slide_toggle1. slide_toggle2 etcetc

```
$(".slide_toggle").hover(function () {
    $(".slide_up").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a small change to make it local to that parent is all you need, otherwise all the `.slide_up` elements will slide

```
$(".slide_toggle").hover(function () {
    $(".slide_up", this).slideToggle("fast");
});
```